# insert xcom values to table in airflow

Tags: airflow

I have requirement, where I have save value to xcom (eg key = db_val). Now need to read the same value and insert into database table.
How to prepare SQL with value from xcom_pull, to be passed in Bigquery_operator or in BashOperator
Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Jinja template

```
INSERT_ROWS_QUERY = ("INSERT DATASET.TABLE_1 VALUES ({{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='task_ids', key='db_val');")

insert_query_job = BigQueryInsertJobOperator(
    task_id="insert_query_job",
    configuration={
        "query": {
            "query": INSERT_ROWS_QUERY,
        }
    },
)
```